# Installing Prosper 202 - Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php

I am trying to get Prosper 202 tracking software to run on a VPS account hosted by GoDaddy and keep getting this error when I run it :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/theprofitview/public_html/202-config/setup-config.php on line 139

Not sure what the problem is however I think it might be at their end and they don't have a clue.

Just tried it with a new database and gives me the same error....

Comment: It's on their end. They don't have the mysqli driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think mysqli extension is enabled for your server. You can try this by creating a file and add phpinfo() function in that.

On executing this script you can see all enabled modules.

Please contact godaddy and enable mysqli extension.